# Change the active tab in browser from console

Tags: javascript, console, automated-tests

I am new to Javascript and any help with my problem is appreciated.

I want to automate the process of inputting data into the website. For that, I need to create a javascript code to be run in the browser console. As an example, the code will have to change the active tab from "ZONE A" to "ZONE B" (see attached picture). For more info, the picture provides a print screen of the website and the inspection code.

[It is the print screen of the browser and the element inspect ][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWFag.png

Answer (score -1):

I solved it with puppeteer. Now learning selenium

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).